# Is it a good idea to use method_missing on nil in ruby

Tags: ruby

In ruby I'm tired of constantly checking if an object has all necessary properties and sub-properties before using them like

```
if (obj && obj[:a] && obj[:a][:b] && obj[:a][:b][:c] && obj[:a][:b][:c] > 0)
    # do something useful
end
```

Is it a good idea to avoid this by defining `method_missing` on `NilClass` to return `nil`?

```
class NilClass
    def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
        nil
    end
end
```

This way with properly written comparisons I can use default values to handle everything.
I can even compare to other expressions like

```
if (obj[:a][:b][:c] > 0)
    # do something useful
else
    # default behaviour if obj[:a][:b][:c] <= 0 or obj[:a][:b][:c] is undefined
end
```

In exceptional cases I can always manually check for `nil`.

What can get broken?

Comment: The expression "playing with fire" comes to mind. A simple example: `(["chicken", "pig"].index("chikcen") + 1 == 1) ? 1 : 2 # => 2`. Here `:+` invokes `method_missing`.

Comment: This counterexample seems to be not so counter- after all... Looks like what's written is: if there is `chikcen` then return `1`, otherwise return `2` which is precisely what's happening with this method_missing. It would actually be great if you could find a real-life counterexample. Probably my question will become meaningless then.

Comment: You will agree that if "chicken" weren't misspelled `1` would be returned. Here `index("chikcen")` returns `nil`, `method missing` causes `nil + 1` to return `nil` and `nil == 1` evaluates `false`, so the misspelling will result in a  surprise at the dinner table.

Comment: Yes, but if `method_missing` is not used this example still looks odd. I would never use it this way in real-life situation, because it is known that `#index` can return `nil`. Instead I would either use `if ([...].index(...)) #found else #not found` or `if ( ([...].index(...) || -1) + 1 == 1 ) ...`. In both cases `method_missing` gives the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Using Hash.fetch would allow you to return false if it doesn't exist and short circuit that conditional.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch

```
if obj.fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:b, {}).fetch(:c, false)
  #useful stuff
end
```

And as was mentioned in the comments if you really didn't want to check if this object was a hash not you could do 
`(obj||{}).fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:b, {}).fetch(:c, false)`

Comment: `{ a: 1 }.fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:b, {}) #=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'fetch' for 1:Fixnum`.

Comment: Cary, error is in your example `{a:1}`, `1` is successfully fetched from it and is not a hash

Comment: @Vasfed, what's your point? `1.fetch(:b, {})` raises an exception. Presumably, the OP wants a graceful conclusion.

Comment: @CarySwoveland True, but in the original example it is three nested hashes.  If you had less than that you should remove the appropriate amount of `fetch` calls

Comment: The point of my example is that one wants `h[:a][:b]` if that object exists, without knowing what `h` looks like.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, you're right, it should be `(h||{}).fetch(...`

Comment: Jared, the problem is that if any of your `fetch`'s return anything other than a hash you get a no method error; e.g., `({a: 1}||{}).fetch(:a, {}).fetch(:b, {}).fetch(:c, false) #=>NoMethodError: undefined method 'fetch' for 1:Fixnum`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ah, the lightbulb just clicked.  Yea I suppose that would be the case

Answer (score 2):

You have not made clear what `obj` is, but I assume it is a hash.

Not immediately obvious if it will break something, but there are better ways than to define such method, so you should avoid doing so.

This question has been repeatedly asked on stackoverflow, with several solutions, but the newest and the best way to do this is to use `Hash#dig` coming with [Ruby 2.3](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11643).

```
obj.dig(:a, :b, :c)
```

Comment: I can imagine a conversation between xaxa and his/her lead: "If you don't mind, I'd like to wait for v.2.3 so I can use `dig`."

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `obj` is a hash and none of the innermost values are `nil`, you don't have to cool your heals waiting for `Hash#dig`:

```
v = get_it_if_you_can(obj, :a, :b, :c)
if v
  # do something
end
```

where:

```
def get_it_if_you_can(h, *args)
  args.reduce(h) { |o,k| o && (o.is_a?(Hash) ? o[k] : nil) }
end
```

For example:

```
h = { a: { b: { c: "yes" } } }

get_it_if_you_can(h, :a )             #=> {:b=>{:c=>"yes"}} 
get_it_if_you_can(h, :a, :b )         #=> {:c=>"yes"} 
get_it_if_you_can(h, :a, :b, :c )     #=> "yes" 
get_it_if_you_can(h, :b, :a, :c )     #=> nil 
get_it_if_you_can(h, :a, :b, :c, :d ) #=> nil
```

Another way:

```
def get_it_if_you_can(h, *args)
  args.reduce(h) { |o,k| o[k] } rescue nil
end

get_it_if_you_can(h, :a )             #=> {:b=>{:c=>"yes"}} 
get_it_if_you_can(h, :a, :b )         #=> {:c=>"yes"} 
get_it_if_you_can(h, :a, :b, :c )     #=> "yes" 
get_it_if_you_can(h, :b, :a, :c )     #=> nil 
get_it_if_you_can(h, :a, :b, :c, :d ) #=> nil
```

I don't like this as well because other errors may be masked:

```
def get_it_if_you_can(h, *args)
  args.redcue(h) { |o,k| o[k] } rescue nil
end

get_it_if_you_can(h, :a, :b, :c )     #=> nil
```

This error would slip though even if we tried to narrow the exception class:

```
def get_it_if_you_can(h, *args)
  begin
    args.redcue(h) { |o,k| o[k] }
  rescue NoMethodError
    nil
  end
end
```

Here's another problem with rescuing the exception. If:

```
h = { a: { "yes"=>1 } }
```

you might expect:

```
get_it_if_you_can(h, :a, "yes", 1)
```

to return `nil`, but it returns `0`. That's because the successive values of the block variables are as follows:

```
o #=>{:a=>{"yes"=>1}}
k #=> :a

o #=> {"yes"=>1}
k #=> "yes"

o #=> 1,
k #=> 1
```

and

```
1[1] = 0
```

(See [Fixnum#[]](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D))

Comment: This (second version with `rescue nil`) seems to be the best solution so far.

Comment: My preference is for the first, for the reason given, but I can't say it's "better".

Comment: The first one applies to `Hash`es. while the second can be applied to any object responding to `[]`

Answer (score 1):

There are a thousand things that can break if you don't expect them. E.g. you won't notice many typos of method names as they silently get eaten by the `method_missing`.

Still, for many people what you are proposing is a desirable thing to have if used correctly. Because of this, Ruby 2.3 will contain a special syntax for [a save navigation operator](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537):

```
foo&.bar
```

For hashes, you can use [Hash#dig](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11643) in Ruby 2.3 similar to this:

```
if obj && obj.dig(:a, :b, :c, default: 0) > 0
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Nice news that they are planning to introduce this feature

Answer (score 0):

`method_missing` affects performance, because it is only checked after everything else, plus additional context allocation etc.
Common pattern is to define method with encountered name, but this is not the case.

Plus you are potentially buying yourself several hours of painful debug time if `nil` shows unexpectedly somewhere else in your code.

Best solution is to use already mentioned `Hash#fetch`, or if you want to be radical - make your hashes to return a special empty hash when key is missing

```
> (h = {a:1}).default = Class.new(Hash){ define_method(:default){|k| self }; define_method(:nil?){true}; define_method(:==){|a|a==nil}}.new
> h[:foo][:bar]
{}
> h[:foo][:bar].nil?
true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `method_missing` is the wrong tool for the job. Instead, I would extract a method.

You haven't explained the significance of `obj[:a][:b][:c] > 0`, so I'll guess:

```
def positive_value_for_c? obj
  begin
    obj[:a][:b][:c] > 0
  rescue NoMethodError
    false
  end
end
```